# Introductory books for $\frak{E}$ $_p(I)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

Are there any books besides *Abstract Harmonic Analysis* by Hewitt and Ross to study  ‎$\frak{E}$$_p(I)$?

**Where  $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is**: ‎Let $ I $ be an arbitrary index set‎. ‎For each $i\in I$, let $H_i$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space of dimension $d_i$‎, ‎and let $a_i$ be a real number $\geq{1}$‎. ‎The $\ast$-algebra $\prod_{i\in{I}}\mathcal{B}(H_i)$‎, ‎will denoted by $\frak{E}$$(I)$. With scalar multiplication‎, ‎addition‎, ‎multiplication‎, ‎and the adjoint of an element are defined coordinatewise, it will be an algebra.

‎Let $E=(E_i)_{i}$ be an element of $\frak{E}$${(I)}.$ For $p\geq0$‎, ‎we define
‎$$\|E\|_{p}=\Big( \sum_{i=1}{a_i\|E_i\|}^{p}_{\varphi_p}\Big)^{1/p}$$‎
‎and‎
‎$$\|E\|_{\infty}=\sup\{\|E_i\|_{\varphi_{\infty}},~i\in I\}.$$‎
‎For $p\geq0$‎, ‎$\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is defined as the set of all $E\in\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ for which $\|E\|_{p}<\infty.$ Hewitt and Ross haves shown that for $1\leq p\leq\infty$‎, $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is a Banach algebra).

**‎Note that for** $\|E_i\|_{\varphi_p}=$ $E_i$'s schatten $p$-norm:
‎‎$o\leq p<\infty$‎,
‎$$\|E_i\|_{\varphi_p}=\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|s_{j}^{i}|}^p\Big)^{1/p}$$ and‎
‎$$\|E_i\|_{\varphi_{\infty}}=\sup\lbrace{s_{1}^{i},s_{2}^{i},...,s_{d_{i}}^{i}}\rbrace,$$‎
‎where $(s_{1}^{i},s_{2}^{i},...,s_{d_{i}}^{i})$ is the sequence of eigenvalues of operator $|E_{i}|$‎, ‎written in any order.

Comment: Let me ask two questions ... :
(1) You introduce $\mathfrak I$ without defining it. May it be that $\mathfrak{I}$ equals the arbitrary index set $I\:$? (2) If I understand correctly, we approach the terrain of the Schatten ideals: When choosing $I=\mathbb N$ and $d_i, a_i=1\:\forall i$, then we deal with a set of diagonal operators which is isomorphic to the sequence space $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$. Letting the $d_i$ grow, one approaches the Schatten ideal $\ell^p(H)$. Can one reach the latter completely by your construction?

Comment: ... and make one proposal: Would you mind to edit your question (incl. spelling) to get it more readable?

Comment: This is the first time I have been scared away by a font.

Comment: It's  because of weak English. I editted it, hope to it works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt whether the Banach algebras $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$, where $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, are discussed at other places than $\S 28$ of *Abstract Harmonic Analysis* by Hewitt & Ross. The reason is that $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ are considered in $\S 28$ in order to introduce the Fourier transform on compact groups. However, it seems that the setting of $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is more general than in fact needed in order to introduce the Fourier transform on compact groups. For example, the Fourier transform on compact groups is covered in Folland's *A First Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* and Deitmar's *Principles of Harmonic Analysis*, but $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ does not really occur in these treatments. Therefore, I think the Banach algebras $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ are really part of Hewitt & Ross' approach to the Fourier transform on compact groups and do not occur outside this approach.

Most of the theory related to $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is in Naimark's *Normed Algebras* and Dixmier's *Von Neumann Algebras*. I am not aware of any reference that covers exactly the algebras $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ other than Hewitt & Ross, but it seems Von Neumann introduced some related concepts in his paper *Some matrix-inequalities and metrization of matric space* for the first time.

Is there a special reason why you are interested in a (more) introductory book on $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$? I don't think *Abstract Harmonic Analysis* is ideal for someone that wants an introduction into harmonic analysis, but the volumes are very self-contained and contain in general full details. Furthermore, all the necessary background material for the treatment of the Banach algebras $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ is in the appendices.

Comment: At the first, sorry for my weak English and thank you for your answer. I am working on $\frak{E}$$_p(I)$ for my thesis, I am trying to study it of its matrix aspect than its Harmonic Analysis aspects.

Comment: @Takhteh_pareh. Thanks for your comment. Regarding the matrix aspects, you might want to have a look into Von Neumann's paper *Some matrix-inequalities and metrization of matric space*. This paper is, of course, not introductory, but I think Von Neumann introduced some of the concepts related to $\frak{E}$$_p (I)$ for the first time.